# Printing minimum path sum path (matrix)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

Solving [leetcode problem][1] which is as follow:

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right, which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

An example grid: `grid = [[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]`

My dp solution:

```
    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int [][]dp = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        int sum = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i<grid[0].length; i++) {
            sum+=grid[0][i];
            dp[0][i] = sum;
        }
        sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++) {
            sum = sum+grid[i][0];
            dp[i][0] = sum;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<grid[0].length; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = grid[i][j]+Math.min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<dp.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<dp[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ",dp[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return dp[grid.length-1][grid[0].length-1];
    }
```

The above solution is correct and gives the answer as `7` for the sample grid. I also print the 2d dp array which is as follows:

```
1 4 5 
2 7 6 
6 8 7
```

I also understand that if I trace the path in reverse from bottom right using above matrix, I can easily print the elements picked at each point. This will give me the full path. **My challenge is that in my recursive solution with memoization, I am unable to leverage the memoized 2d array to do the same.**

Recursive solution

```
    public int recurse(int [][]grid, int x, int y,int [][]dp) {
        if(x == grid.length || y == grid[0].length) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(dp[x][y]!=-1) return dp[x][y];
        if(x == grid.length-1 && y == grid[0].length-1) return grid[x][y];
        var r1 = recurse(grid,x+1,y,dp);
        var r2 = recurse(grid,x,y+1,dp);
        dp[x][y] = grid[x][y]+Math.min(r1,r2);
        return dp[x][y];
    }
```

Here is how I call the recursive method and also print the 2d memoized array

```
    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int [][]dp = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        for(int []a:dp) {
            Arrays.fill(a,-1);
        }
        var v  = recurse(grid,0,0,dp);
        for(int i = 0; i<dp.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<dp[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ",dp[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

The memoized array is

```
7 6 3 
8 7 2 
7 3 -1
```

I also get that the result in this case gets stored at `(0,0)` of the memoized array based on how the recursion is invoked.

**I am unable to leverage the above array to find the path when I go the memoization route**
Secondly, if instead of invoking recursion as `recurse(grid,0,0,dp)`, **how can I invoke it to write the result at bottom right?**
[1]: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/description/

Comment: You already have one 2d array to store the sum of the path. What's stopping you from creating a second 2d array to store which node to traverse to, from a given one?

Comment: Not clear what you mean honestly

Comment: Your 2d array `dp`  is defined by `dp[i][j]` is the minimum value of the path to `(i, j)`, starting from `(0, 0)`. I'm saying you should create a second 2d array, say `path` where `path[i][j]` contains the position `(i', j')` where `(i', j')` should be traversed from `(i, j)` in order to recover the path whose value is defined by `dp`.

Comment: Yes i get that part but I am not clear in my recursive function at what point this other array should be populated. It is not very obvious

Comment: You're already adding the smaller of the neighbors to your first array, so add the coordinates of the smaller neighbor to the array that stores the actual path as well.

Comment: Please modify the snippet and share as an answer if you are comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to come down to this: how to have the recursive algorithm produce the same `dp` matrix as the iterative solution.

If you just perform your recursive procedure backwards, starting from the bottom-right instead of the top-left, and you make sure to write in `dp[0][0]` the value of `grid[0][0]` (base case), then you get the exact same `dp` matrix as in the first, iterative solution:

```java
    public int recurse(int[][] grid, int x, int y, int[][] dp) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (dp[x][y] != -1) return dp[x][y];
        var r1 = recurse(grid, x - 1, y, dp);
        var r2 = recurse(grid, x, y - 1, dp);
        dp[x][y] = grid[x][y] + Math.min(r1, r2);
        return dp[x][y];
    }

    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int [][]dp = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        for (int[] a : dp) {
            Arrays.fill(a, -1);
        }
        dp[0][0] = grid[0][0]; // Add this
        var v  = recurse(grid, grid.length - 1, grid[0].length - 1, dp);
        for (int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dp[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", dp[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. As always, you have been a life saver. I must say, start a Youtube channel or something on Algorithms!